# User roles from custom database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I'm creating an app with ASP.NET WebForms. I have custom database with users table. It contains name and role. How can I add roles from DB to website? I want to use something like this:

```
<location path="path"> 
   <system.web>
      <authorization> 
         <allow roles="role"/>
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

where `role` should be imported.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a custom membership provider? Can you provide code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [implement a custom RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.ASPX).

As a minimum you need to implement `Intialize` (of course) and the methods `GetRolesForUser` and `IsUserInRole`.  The other methods are only needed if you want to be able to administer roles through the RoleProvider.

`IsUserInRole` can often be implemented as something close to:

```
public bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
{
    return GetRolesForUser(username).Contains(roleName);
}
```

so apart from initialization, which in your case will probably only be storing a database connection string, you only have one simple method to implement.